# не отрабатывает условие - PHP БД

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, где ошибся?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(mo.id) AS ido,
       mo.userid AS usi
FROM modx_shopkeeper3_orders AS mo,
     modx_zadan AS mz
WHERE mo.gotov=1
  AND mo.id<>mz.id_order
ORDER BY mo.id ASC
```

Вывожу все записи из таблицы `modx_shopkeeper3_orders` если `modx_shopkeeper3_orders.id` не равен `modx_zadan.id_order`.

Но почему-то запрос выдает записи, которые есть и в одной таблице, и во второй.

Comment: а ты дай структуры таблиц и их данные мы и проверим.... http://sqlfiddle.com/  в помощь ..... заодно напиши ожидаемый результат

Comment: потому что во второй таблице обязательно найдется хотя бы одна запись у которой id не совпадает с первой. если нужны только те, которых нет, используйте `NOT IN()`/`NOT EXISTS` или LEFT JOIN с проверкой на NULL в части WHERE